# WPF How To Bind Two Nested Usercontrols

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I need to bind a user control data context with other control property :

```
    <StackPanel>
        <custom:UserControl1 x:Name="UC1"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel>
        <custom:UserControl2 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UC1, Path=MySelectedValue}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Of course i have implemented a dependency property 'MySelectedValue' on UserControl1. 
The following does not work. I guess because it searches the ElementName on the visual tree and could not find it because both controls are parallel nested.

How could i get the above to work?

Thanks,

Comment: Strange, it should work. For debugging, you can try to set `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High`. See http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html or http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52. HTH.

Comment: Upon futher review, I agree as well. I tried a simple repro with the given info and it works for me. Can you provide any additional details?

Comment: You guys are absolutely correct. My dependency property was not implemented right. Vlad, please add an answer for this, so i can mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlad had solved this for me mentioning that everything is actually fine!
I had my dependency property not defined properly.

It seems that the 'ElementName' binding works even if the element is nested on parallel with the calling element.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How did you define the MySelectedValue DependencyProperty (is it set to [BindsTwoWayByDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.bindstwowaybydefault.aspx))?